# Kendo DataSource, AngularJS - undefined property

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-observable

I want to fill a grid with a complex json returned from a webservice. My json contains two things:

- data: array with the records that will fill the grid
- columns: array with the config(layout) of the grid

I have successfully filled the grid with the "data" by specifying the schema.data.

My problem is with the grid config (layout). I get the columns array on the `requestEnd` event of the datasource and i add it to the `customersSource` (datasource) so i can access it in the gridOptions.

The problem is that even though when i log the `customersSource` object i see that the cols array i added, is there and is filled with the proper data the `$scope.mainGridOptions.columns` isn't set to `customersSource.cols`.

I think that this may have to do with the fact that `customersSource.cols` is set asynchronously but shouldn't angular take care of this with it's databinding?

Also i have read in [Data source vs. Angular](http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/datasource) that i may have to set something as Observable but i am confused of what to do exactly.

How can i fix this?

**Here is my code:**

```
var customersSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "http://....",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "data"
        },
        requestEnd: function (e) {
            this.cols = e.response.columns;
        }
    });

$scope.mainGridOptions = {
        dataSource: customersSource, // OK
        columns: customersDataSource.cols, // undefined - uses default
        height: 500,
        scrollable: true,
        selectable: true
    };
```

**Here is my JSON**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "firstname": "Dalton",
      "lastname": "Holden",
      "gender": "male",
      "email": "daltonholden@tellifly.com",
      "phone": "871-407-2973",
      "address": "22 National Drive, Brenton, Louisiana",
      "birthday": "21/04/1965",
      "currency": "GBP"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "firstname": "Allyson",
      "lastname": "Odom",
      "gender": "female",
      "email": "allysonodom@tellifly.com",
      "phone": "922-548-2725",
      "address": "44 Quincy Street, Thynedale, Georgia",
      "birthday": "28/08/1961",
      "currency": "CHF"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "firstname": "Sweet",
      "lastname": "Branch",
      "gender": "male",
      "email": "sweetbranch@tellifly.com",
      "phone": "880-593-2244",
      "address": "81 Fenimore Street, Veguita, Missouri",
      "birthday": "08/08/1953",
      "currency": "AUD"
    }
  ],

  "columns": [
    {
      "field": "firstname",
      "title": "Frist Name",
      "width": 200,
      "attributes": {
        "class": "",
        "style": "text-align: left;"
      },
      "headerAttributes": {
        "class": "table-header-cell",
        "style": "text-align: left;"
      }
    },
    {
      "field": "lastname",
      "title": "Last Name",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "",
        "style": "text-align: left;"
      },
      "headerAttributes": {
        "class": "table-header-cell",
        "style": "text-align: left;"
      }
    },
    {
      "field": "gender",
      "title": "Gender",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "",
        "style": "text-align: left;"
      },
      "headerAttributes": {
        "class": "table-header-cell",
        "style": "text-align: left;"
      }
    },
    {
      "field": "email",
      "title": "e-mail",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "",
        "style": "text-align: left;"
      },
      "headerAttributes": {
        "class": "table-header-cell",
        "style": "text-align: left;"
      }
    },
    {
      "field": "phone",
      "title": "Phone Number",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "",
        "style": "text-align: right;"
      },
      "headerAttributes": {
        "class": "table-header-cell",
        "style": "text-align: right;"
      }
    },
    {
      "field": "address",
      "title": "Address",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "",
        "style": "text-align: left;"
      },
      "headerAttributes": {
        "class": "table-header-cell",
        "style": "text-align: left;"
      }
    },
    {
      "field": "birthday",
      "title": "Birthday",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "",
        "style": "text-align: center;"
      },
      "headerAttributes": {
        "class": "table-header-cell",
        "style": "text-align: center;"
      }
    },
    {
      "field": "currency",
      "title": "Currency",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "",
        "style": "text-align: center;"
      },
      "headerAttributes": {
        "class": "table-header-cell",
        "style": "text-align: center;"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**Edit**
I created a plunker of my testing project. As you can see i can fill the grid but i have a problem with the mainGridOptions.columns. Any help will be much appreciated!
http://plnkr.co/edit/5pjFQGkgTivqVkxsFBse

Answer (score 0):

It's because angularjs is unaware of changes made by 3rd party and you miss the magic two-way data binding. although I think promises would work great in your case

```
requestEnd: function (e) {
  $scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.mainGridOptions.columns = e.response.columns
  })
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error? maybe you can expand your code for a better image?

Comment: Yes of course. I will create a plunker and post back.

Comment: I edited my post! You can find all my code in the link at the end.